# Skipping else part in dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to convert a groovy code into DataWeave. I am trying to store values in variable based on a condition.
The pseudo code is as-

```
payload map (value, index) -> (
  if(condition) (
    vars.variableName + {
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "value2",
    "attribute3": "value3"
    }
  )
)
```

as you see that I don't want to use the else part. But in DW else part is mandatory.

So, is there any way that is can skip the else part. I tried this-

```
if(condition)(

)else{}

OR

if(condition)(

)else""
```

but this adds additional "" or {} in the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just have the else be the preexisting variable without adding anything to it (needs initialized before this script).

```
payload map (value, index) -> (
  if(condition) (
    vars.variableName ++ {
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "value2",
    "attribute3": "value3"
    }
  )
  else vars.variableName
)
```

Or if vars.variableName hasn't been created yet you can default it to an empty object so you can add to it later in another script. However if the variable hasn't been initialized yet the condition in the `if-else` must direct the processing to the `else` clause. Otherwise you will get an error if trying to append an object to a variable that is `null`.

```
payload map (value, index) -> (
  if(condition) (
    vars.variableName ++ {
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "value2",
    "attribute3": "value3"
    }
  )
  else vars.variableName default {}
)
```

BTW need to use `++` to combine objects

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to add an input and a corresponding output so that we can help out more/better.

Now to your question: the DW `if-expression` is just that an expression, it must return a value, hence why the `else` must be there.

Based upon your expression you can do something like this:

```
if (condition) (
  vars.variableName + {attribute1: "value1"}
) else (
  vars.variableName
)
```

I am not certain whether this will work however, unless the target of your output is the variable.